# Read(*,*) causes (unit = 5, file = 'stdin') Fortran runtime error: End of file

Tags: fortran, fortran90

I am trying to make a small code snippet in Fortran 90 to read in a file name from the user, and I know that it should be simple, but I just can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

The script is:

```pascal
program test
  implicit none
  Character (Len = 15) :: filename

  Write(*,*) 'Input file name'
  Read(*,*) filename
  Write(*,*) 'So the file is called',filename
end program test
```

And then I compile it on an ubuntu system using gfortran:

```
$ gfortran test.f90 -o test.exe
```

It compiles fine, but when I run `./test.exe`, I get the following output:

```sh
$ ./test.exe 
Input file name 
At line 6 of file test.f90 (unit = 5, file = 'stdin') 
Fortran runtime error: End of file 

Error termination. Backtrace:
#0  0x7f435e83b32a
```

when what I was expecting to get was:

```sh
$ ./test.exe 
Input file name 
[program pauses while user inputs text] 
So the file is called [text the user inputted]
```

I just can't seem to find an example of this error or how to fix it online. Can someone please tell me where I'm going wrong here?

Comment: I think we need more information on the system you're using (Win/Mac/Linux) and how exactly you are running the program. It looks a bit as if it didn't have a standard input stream, which is... weird.

Comment: Welcome, please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Please give us more details. What is yur operating system? What is your compiler? How exactly are you running the code? In what kind of terminal?

Comment: also which version of gfortran are you using?

Comment: I am running on a virtual Ubuntu 20.04 LTS release environment within a windows computer. The compiler version is GNU Fortran 7.5.0 .

I can compile and run other fortran scripts just fine in the set up. It's only the READ command that is triggering an error.

Comment: it sounds like your stdin is broken within the virtual machine. can you try to supply an input directly to the program, e.g. `$ echo "123" | ./test.exe`?

Comment: Your test with the echo pipe suggests to me that your gfortran install works, but it doesn't yet solve your real problem. In my native virtual Ubuntu 20.04 LTS with GNU Fortran (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) 9.3.0 your program works perfectly (compiled and run from bash.) So there seems to be something wrong with your shell or terminal. I suggest you edit your question to confirm you use the bash shell, and which virtualizer you use (WSL/VirtualBox/VMware etc.)

Comment: (for completeness, I found that version 7.5.0 also works fully on my machine: it accepts keyboard input, however my command is `gfortran-7 test.f90 -o test7.exe && ./test7.exe ` )